# Using greek letters in a table when using Palatino font

Tags: tables, math-mode, greek, mathpazo

I am trying to write an article with Palatino font. I loaded the following packages, among others:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{avant}
```

In my first attempt of writing the letter `$\Omega$` it worked. But when I attempted to write this letter inside of a table cell, I obtained the following output:

[image: Code output]

Where instead of the black squares in the middle column, it should appear the letter `$\Omega$`. The piece code I wrote for this table is the following:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   Filtre & Resistència & Condensador\\
   \hline
   1 &  $R_1=10\hspace{1mm} \mathrm{k\Omega}$ & $C_1=1\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{nF}$\\
   2 & $R_2=100\hspace{1mm} \mathrm{\Omega}$ & $C_2=100\hspace{1mm} \mathrm{nF}$\\
   3 & $R_3=1\hspace{1mm} \mathrm{M\Omega}$ & $C_3=10\hspace{1mm} \mathrm{pF}$\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

So there's my question. I don't know how to fix this, maybe I should load a package that allows me to use greek letters in a table when using this font, or something different. If I write greek letters out of a table, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mathrm{\Omega}` is wrong as it points to a non existent character. You should use `siunitx`, instead of doing manual markup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Filtre & Resistència & Condensador\\
\hline
1 & $R_1=  \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}$ & $C_1=\SI{1}{\nano\farad}$ \\
2 & $R_2= \SI{100}{\ohm}$      & $C_2=\SI{100}{\nano\farad}$ \\
3 & $R_3=   \SI{1}{\mega\ohm}$ & $C_3=\SI{10}{\pico\farad}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I see it's more comfortable to do that by using the units package instead of typing the units everytime. Good answer, and well seen that the text was written in Catalan!

Comment: @Airman01 I guessed from *Resistència*; the grave accent was revealing.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `\mathrm` command and simply use `\Omega` command alone. You will get omega symbol

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple solution and it worked perfectly as well!

Answer (score 1):

I propose  two solutions based on `siunitx` and some improvements with the `makecell` and `booktabs` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo, avant}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, makecell, siunitx}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{1ex}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
    \hline
    Filtre & \thead{Resistència} & \thead{Condensador} \\
    \hline
    1 & $R_1=10 \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}$ &
    $C_1= \SI{1}{\nano F}$\\
    2 & $R_2=\SI{100}{\ohm}$ & $C_2=\SI{100}{\nano F}$ \\
    3 & $R_3=\SI{1}{\mega\ohm}$ & $ C_3=\SI{10}{\pico F}$ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cll}
    \toprule
    Filtre & \thead{Resistència} & \thead{Condensador} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    1 & $R_1=10 \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}$ &
    $C_1= \SI{1}{\nano F}$\\
    \addlinespace
    2 & $R_2=\SI{100}{\ohm}$ & $C_2=\SI{100}{\nano F}$ \\
    \addlinespace
    3 & $R_3=\SI{1}{\mega\ohm}$ & $ C_3=\SI{10}{\pico F}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]